# Vagrant up fails with Laravel: 'The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status'

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant

New to Laravel and Vagrant, never put up a virtual machine any way other than via MAMP.
New to using Terminal in general.

Running on Mac OSX 10.9.
Vagrantfile (and hopefully soon Laravel) is placed in a folder in Documents.

Receiving error:

```
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

[Log since 'vagrant up'](http://pastebin.com/M14mmj4M)

[Used vagrant files](https://github.com/philipbrown/vagrant-laravel)

UPDATE: When accessing the designated VM address through my browser, I am greeted by a `403 Forbidden`

EDIT: Link to terminal log updated after fixing laravel installation issues regarding mcrypt.

UPDATE: Tried solution described [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1659) by adding the following to `/etc/sudoers`. Problem not fixed.

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
Defaults:vagrant !requiretty
```

Answer (score 1):

The artisan file isn't there.

```
php artisan migrate #fails
```

I can't tell exactly what should be in /var/www, but it seems to me like Laravel isn't getting set up properly. Try `vagrant ssh` to snoop around in /var/www (ls /var/www) and see what's there/what's missing.

Comment: An update is offered when running it, but when trying to update by `do-release-upgrade`, it displays `This session appears to be running under ssh. It is not recommended to perform a upgrade over ssh currently because in case of failure it is harder to recover.` . Should i run the update?

Comment: Also, what do I want to do after running `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: Forget the upgrade for now. After you login with `vagrant ssh`, try `ls /var/www` to see the directory listing and make sure the laravel files (specifically `artisan`) are there.

Comment: this only returns `html`. what's happening?

Comment: I think you need to get a better understanding of your bootstrap script. Laravel isn't getting installed where you expect and without a copy of the project it's difficult to say why.

Comment: I went ahead and started using MAMP for developing on Laravel instead. Not the best solution, I know. I will return to attempting to set Laravel up on Vagrant another day. Upvote for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
vagrant ssh
```

when you success login, run the command like below:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

maybe `70` or `60` is the begining of rules filename.

than reload your virtualbox,try it maybe the right way to solve the matter.

Answer (score -3):

If you have this error, after

```
vagrant up
```

you can use

```
vagrant ssh
```

It let you launch your server.